# Macro en Google Sheet que inicia otra Hoja de Calculo

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, enlace

Estoy buscando la mandera de generar una macro en Google Sheet que al ejecutarla, me redireccione a otra Hoja de Google Sheet. Primero queria saber si esto es posible y si no lo es, queria saber de que otra manera puedo lograr esto.

El codigo que tengo en google sheet hasta ahora, ejecuta un OpenByUrl pero la pagina queda cargando y no inicia la otra hoja de calculo. Les dejo mi codigo para esta funcion :
var GastosMensualesHoja = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('Where the Url')
GastosMensualesHoja.setActiveSheet(GastosMensualesHoja.getSheetByName('Reporte'), true);
}; ```

Answer (score 0):

Esta secuencia de comando te va permitir posicionarte en una hoja al abrir la planilla google

```
function onOpen(e) {

  // Abrir la planilla se posiciona en la hoja Sheet2

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                            .getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  sheet.activate()

}
```